# Access data from Google Team Drive in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive

is there a way to access my data from Google Team Drive? I used the provided code, but can only access my normal drive and not Team Drive:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the REST API to [manage your Team Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-teamdrives). Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-teamdrives). Here's a list of [methods](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/teamdrives) for this resource:

> - create
>
>   - Creates a new Team Drive.
> - delete
>
>   - Permanently deletes a Team Drive for which the user is an organizer. The Team Drive cannot contain any untrashed items.
> - get
>
>   - Gets a Team Drive's metadata by ID.
> - list
>
>   - Lists the user's Team Drives.
> - update
>
>   - Updates a Team Drive's metadata